# set App to Device Owner using adb not working due to Accounts on device

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to set my app to Device Owner on my device using adb ("adb shell dpm set-device-owner...") but it is giving me the following error:

"Not allowed to set the device owner because there are already several users on the device"

Having looked to solve the problem I checked Settings > Accounts and there are no users in there even though adb is telling me there are?

I am using a Lenovo Tab 4 HD - 7 Inch running 7.1.1

My method worked previously on a Samsung Tab A 7 inch running 4.4.2

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ok. Sir, I guess you must try the following steps

1. reset the device.
2. skip the account entry in the Gmail
3. try to run the adb shell command and with luck, this will work 
   Note: Check your tabled/mobile adb is properly installed or not and run the adb shell command after you have installed the app on cell/tablet.

Comment: Tried this and still no luck, I skip any account signing in on first setup and then do the adb shell and it still gives me the same error. Its like Lenovo have put a hidden account on or something?

Comment: Dear Sir, I suggest you please send me your screenshots so that I can review I have applied on many tabs and the cell phone it works on all devices let me see your problem maybe I can help you out.

Comment: @SliderUK have you find solution for that? I am having same problem there is no account logged in still getting this error. Reset phone is not option for me

Comment: @ShahbazPirzada